# grid columns not displaying correctly

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, bourbon, neat

I am using Bourbon Neat. I set some breakpoints in grid settings and for the mobile version I set 4 like this:

```
$mobile: new-breakpoint(max-width 480px 4);
```

I set the left and right containers like 3 for left and 1 for right; like this:

```
.demo
{

  @include outer-container;

  .leftContainer
  {
    @include span-columns( 6 );
    background-color:crimson;
    @include media($mobile) { 
      @include span-columns( 3 of 4);
    }
  }

  .rightContainer
  {
    @include span-columns( 6 );
    background-color:blue;
  }

  @include media($mobile) { 
    @include span-columns( 1 of 4 );
  }
}
```

But somehow the containers stack on each other instead of spanning 3 and 1 columns. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell without seeing the HTML too, but looks like the .rightContainer code is what's breaking. The second @include media($mobile) {} is outside of the .rightContainer {}

Try this:

```
.demo{

  @include outer-container;

  .leftContainer {
    @include span-columns( 6 );
    background-color:crimson;

    @include media($mobile) { 
        @include span-columns( 3 of 4);
    }
  }

  .rightContainer{
    @include span-columns( 6 );
    background-color:blue;

    @include media($mobile) { 
        @include span-columns( 1 of 4 );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: smharley has it correct, your mobile include is not positioned correctly

Answer (score 1):

You are using `@include span-columns(3 of 4)` but the `.leftContainer` and `.rightContainer` aren´t nested inside another div with `span-columns()`, so you should not pass the columns of the parent as an argument.

Try this:

```
.demo{

  @include outer-container;

  .leftContainer {
    @include span-columns( 6 );
    background-color:crimson;

    @include media($mobile) { 
        @include span-columns(3); /*Change this line*/
    }
  }

  .rightContainer{
    @include span-columns( 6 );
    background-color:blue;

    @include media($mobile) { 
        @include span-columns(1); /*and this one*/
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe you can check [this documentation](http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/#span-columns) for more help.